# Implement T for collections of &T? (Like [&T]?)

Tags: rust

I have some trait, `MyTrait`:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self, ...) -> f32
}
```

And I want to blanket implement `MyTrait` for collections of `&MyTrait`. For example:

```rust
let myA: impl MyTrait = ...;
let myB: impl MyTrait = ...;

fn bar<T: MyTrait>(f: &T) -> f32 {
    f.foo()
}

let a = bar(myA);
let b = bar(myB);

assert_equals!(a + b, bar(&[&myA, &myB]));
```

For some reason, I can't get this to work like this:

```rust
impl<T> MyTrait for [&T]
    where T: MyTrait
    {
    fn foo(&self, ...) -> f32 {
        let mut acc = 0.0;
        for f in self.into_iter() {
            acc += f.foo(...);
        }
        acc
    }
}
```

I get this rather cryptic error message:

```
the trait bound `[&MyType; 1]: MyTrait` is not satisfied
help: the following implementations were found:
    <[&T] as MyTrait>
```

Huh?? It just said the implementation wasn't satisfied... but then the type provided is the same. What's going on?

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=87deb94d3117a9765015eb0375c6be61) Can you show a minimal example that actually results in the pasted error?

Comment: the error you show it's an array of size 1, your code use an array of 2. check twice your question

Comment: @user4815162342 Please check the updated example. We can call the function `&[&myA].foo()`, but if we make a function `bar<T: MyTrait>(&T)` then `bar(&myA)` works but `bar(&[&myA])` does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bar(&[&myA])` does not work for two reasons:

- a `[T; 1]` is not a `[T]`. Sometimes it gets automatically converted, but this is not one of them. You have to do the conversion manually, with `bar([&myA].as_ref())` or `bar(&[&myA][..])`.
- Generic functions have an implicit bound on every generic parameter of type `T: Sized`, and `[T]` is unsized, so it does not satisfy the requirements. Write `fn bar<T: MyTrait + ?Sized>` to remove that.

Another alternative, now that generic constants are stable, is to implement the trait for arrays, instead of, or in addition to slices:

```
impl<T, const N: usize> MyTrait for [&T; N]
where
    T: MyTrait,
{
    fn foo(&self) -> f32 {
        self.as_ref().foo()
    }
}
```

Now you can write `bar(&[myA])` and specialize the generic as `bar::<[&A; 1]>()`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Thanks to this answer I was also able to get it working for the generic `IntoIterator`.